# SSH Connection timed out on EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to secure my apache with `Let's Encrypt` on Ubuntu 18.04,

I ran these commands:

> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot 
> $ sudo apt install python-certbot-apache 
> $ sudo ufw enable 
> $ sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'

After the last command, The terminal froze, so I decided to close it and reconnect hoping it would really reconnect. 
Unfortunately, it returns with a message saying:

> ssh: connect to host <...some public ipv4 DNS> port 22: Connection timed out

I checked the security groups to see if `SSH` is set to `Anywhere` and yes its set.

My guess is I messed up the `ufw` configs(or maybe not), but I can't confirm it because I cant ssh to my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup ufw, it's very important to also allow the ssh connection otherwise you will effectively lock yourself out of your server which seems to be the case.